# How to handle TabBar with ListView in Flutter?

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, tabbar

I have spent a couple hours just to find how to change the tint of tab while scrolling the listView until (x) item/header,

I'm start to learn flutter from [here](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe)

and the UI look's like:

[image]

I wonder how to dealing with `ListView` and `tabBar` just in case i'm scrolling until **Flutter is awesome 51** the `tabBar` indicator should change to right, the same things should work with `tabBar`, when i press the `tabBar` **index 51** the `ListView` should scrolling to **Flutter is awesome 51**,

anyone can guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

[TabController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController-class.html)

```
_tabController.animateTo((index))
```

In combination with

[ScrollController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html)

```
final _position = ... // half or top depending on tab selection itemsize and count 
_scrollController.animateTo(_position,
        curve: Curves.linear, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```

If your list items have the same height you could rely on the offset and position from the scroll in order to detect when it reached half.

[Here is an implementation of the ScrollController that will aid you.](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac)

Comment: can you give me a hint why `TabController` and `ScrollController` break the _hiding header on scroll_?

Comment: I am not aware of this issue. Maybe it is better to create a new question thread and provide full details.